# How do I specify the route in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

How do I specify the following URL format in the routing and access the variables (service id, Security id, writedataflag) in the following:

```
 https://<Domain Name or localhost<Port No>>api/<service Id>/<security id>/<writedataflag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the route template.

The following example uses Attribute Routing on a controller action.

```
//matches GET api/<service Id>/<security id>/<writedataflag> 
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{service_id}/{security_id}/{writedataflag}")]
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(int service_id, int security_id, string writedataflag){
    //...    
}
```

the parameter types can be changed to suit your needs. Also consider using parameter constraints.

Read more about that here

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)